# crashing 2.91.0

Tags: modeling

It crashes whenever I change the radius of the torus.

It happens on a brand new project with nothing in it but the torus. Trying to follow the donut tutorial but cannot even start.

Is that a bug?

Running on MacBook Pro 2015, Mojave, AMD Radeon R9 M370X